# Magento 2: How to get admin user detail load by id?

Tags: magento2, admin

I have an admin user id 15, How to load the model to get username and user role?
In Magento1 this was possible using:

```
$adminuserId = 15;
Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminuserId)->getRole()->getData();
```

How does it work in Magento2?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add this to your class and  constructor:

```
protected $userFactory;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory,
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
    ...
}
```

Then create a method in the same class to retrieve the role data:

```
public function getRoleData($userId)
{
    $user = $this->userFactory->create()->load($userId);
    $role = $user->getRole();
    $data = $role->getData();
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use following code:

```
$adminuserId = 15;
$user = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
    'Magento\User\Model\User'
);
$user->load($adminuserId);
```

But it is not recommended to use `ObjectManager` directly in the code.
Try to add `Magento\User\Model\UserFactory` to your class constructor and use it to load customer.

Example:

```
class SomeMyClass
{
    protected $_userFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory
    ) {
        $this->_userFactory = $userFactory;
    }

    public function someFunction()
    {
        $adminuserId = 15;
        $user = $this->_userFactory->create();
        $user->load($adminuserId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**The following will help to get the magento logged user id. Thank you**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$extensionUser = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session')->getUser()->getUsername();
$extensionId = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session')->getUser()->getID();
```

Comment: ObjectManager is deprecated, Please don't use it.